# Sql запрос. Вычислить количество по значению

Tags: sql

Есть таблица продуктов. Каждый продукт по 100гр содержит определенное количество белков, жиров и углеводов.
Можно ли создать запрос, что бы в ответе выдавались продукты и их количество по заданному количеству белков, жиров и углеводов.
Например для 80гр белков - 200 гр курицы и 100 гр рыбы.
Select product_id sum(protein) as protein from products where protein = 80 (знаю, что неверно)

Comment: с таким же успехом можно предложить 300 г курицы и 50 г рыбы.

Comment: У Вас задача не имеет однозначного математического решения.

В Вашем примере 80 гр белков можно набрать, скушав 200 гр курицы и 100 гр рыбы, или 202 гр курицы и 99 гр рыбы и т.п. - это линейное уравнение.

Comment: [однозначное решение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0) находится для случая 3 продукта и 3 составляющих(жиры, белки, углеводы), но если добавлять еще продуктов, то решение не будет однозначным, будет множество решений.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru ну так очевидно, что продуктов будет не 2 и не 3. Также очевидно, что ищут не одну комбинацию, а множество комбинаций из разных продуктов. Вопрос вызывает распределение весов  между продуктами в одной комбинации.

Comment: @teran, если люди задают вопрос значит не очевидно. Я не дописал, что будет бесконечное множество решений. `Вопрос вызывает распределение весов между продуктами в одной комбинации.` - Нету тут никакого вопроса, просто уравнение 200x + 100y = 80 - прямая.